# How to pool Thrift connections among NodeJs cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, connection-pooling, thrift, isomorphic-javascript

**Architecture** : Isomorphic app using nodeJS server, ReactJs and Thrift services.

I am running performance test cases on this app to measure **RPM** (Request Per Minute) nodejs server could handle. I improved the performance by using clusters and pooling thrift connections. But still this app lags behind the RMP numbers of same app based on PLAY framework. Investigation clearly show connection pooling is not as good as its in play and i think its because pool is not shared among clusters.

Now as clusters are different process all together , shall i divide pools among clusters or use master to maintain pool and use message passing for communication.

Performance is done using JMeter.

Pooling is done using cluster-pool module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster-pool)

**Clusters** :

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
// Count the machine's CPUs
    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

// Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
// Code to run if we're in a worker process
    } else {
    app.listen(1338, function () {
        console.log("started..............");
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled the Node app? That's the only way to know what is your bottleneck. It *could* be the connection pooling, but it could also be many other things, such as memory issues (e.g. excessive GC), serialization performance (e.g. the Thrift Java implementation is more efficient), bad load balancing, accidental use of synchronous code (e.g., logging can be problematic with Node), inefficient JavaScript code, and many other causes. Without profiling, there is no way to know.